# How can I hide a row of the table(MyTable) by a row id when I check checkbox(MyCheckbox) and show the row when the checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jquery

How can I hide a row of the table(MyTable) by an id when I check checkbox(MyCheckbox) and show the row when the checkbox(MyCheckbox) is unchecked using Jquery?

Comment: Will the checkbox be in the same row you are trying to hide or show?

Comment: There is a check box for every row in a different table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    var index = $("#myCheckboxes :checkbox").index($(this));
    $("#myTable tr").eq(index).toggle();
});

<table id="myTable">
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="myCheckboxes">
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> checkbox 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> checkbox 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> checkbox 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> checkbox 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Online example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/VdqNt/3/

Answer (score 0):

I would give each row a unique id that may be created from each checkbox's unique id. So if you have a set of checkboxes that all have ids like "toggle-1" then each corresponding row should have an id like "row-toggle-1". Now simple bind a click event to each checkbox and have the row be shown or hidden with a conditional check on the checkbox's checked status.

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // bind a click function to each input element with a class of MyCheckboxes
    $('input.MyCheckboxes').click(function() {

        // select the corresponding table row
        var corresponding_table_row = $('#row-'+this.id)

        // show or hide the row depending on the checked status
        if ( $(this).attr('checked') ) {
            corresponding_table_row.hide();
        else {
            corresponding_table_row.show();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses attributes on the checkbox to match it to the row you want to fiddle with:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td>1-1</td>
            <td>1-2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <td>2-1</td>
            <td>2-2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" data-row="row1">Row 1</input></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" data-row="row2">Row 2</input></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
        $('#' + $(this).data('row')).toggle(!$(this).attr('checked'));
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6WCmk/2/